# Gulp не выподняет таск sass

Tags: gulp, sass

Здравствуйте! Не могу разобраться,почему не выполняется таск sass. Прилагаю скрин окна команд и сам таск.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');  

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/sass/main.sass')
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});
```

Comment: Приложите ещё main.sass пожалуйста.

Comment: Исходя из текста ошибки, у вас в main.sass после body {...} идут пустые фигурные скобки, что вызывает ошибку.

Comment: там очень простая строка body {background-color:#4869D6;}. Я поняла, что он имеет ввиду пустые скобки,но не могу понять, почему так считает

Comment: попробуйте пробел после `background-color:`

Comment: ого! Всего лишь? Сработало! Спасибо большое) Не ожидала,что это может иметь такое серьезное значение